# Debug App with iOS 4.0 Simulator on iOS 5 SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I'm using the latest XCode (4.2), and I need to debug 4.1, 4.2, 4.3 thoroughly.  Presently, the drop down in the upper left corner only gives me the option to debug with the simulator using version 4.3 or 5.0.  I really need to test 4.0, 4.1, 4.2 more thoroughly.  Since I can't seem to find any reliable way to downgrade my test device (3GS) from 5.0 to 4.0+ (it's never been jailbroken), the simulator seems to be my only option to ensure maximum compatibility.

Can anyone point me in the right direction in terms of properly setting up the simulator for older iOS versions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Click on your target in the Xcode Navigator (the upmost item), select `Build Settings`, go to `Deployment`. There you can select several `iOS Deplyment Targets`.

Comment: I have that set to iOS 4.0, but when choosing how to build the game in the top-left drop down, I still only have Simulator iOS 4.3, or Simulator iOS 5.0.  How can I get it to show 4.0, 4.1, 4.2, etc.?